# how can I get instance of the session of Cassandra in TestCassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am unable to figure out how to unit-test my class which access `Cassandra`. I might have to redesign!

I have created a `Play` `Components` class (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext) which creates a cassandra session at application start up.

```
trait CassandraRepositoryComponents {
  def environment: Environment
  def configuration: Configuration
  def applicationLifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle
...
lazy private val cassandraSession: Session = {
val cluster = new Cluster.Builder().
      addContactPoints(uri.hosts.toArray: _*).
      withPort(uri.port).
      withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(defaultConsistencyLevel)).build
val session = cluster.connect
}

}
```

The session thus created is passed to my repo class when the repo class is instantiaited

```
class UsersRepository(utilities:HelperMethods, session: Session,tablename:String) 
  extends CassandraRepository[UserKeys,User](session, tablename, List("bucket","email"))  {
```

//UsersRepository CLASS DOESN'T USE session DIRECTLY. IT PASSES THE session TO CassandraRepository WHICH EVENTUALLY CALLS session.execute TO RUN QUERIES...}

I want to unit test `UsersRepository`. I am using `embedded-cassandra` to test it but it seems `embedded-cassandra` doesn't provide a way to get instance of the session it creates.

question1 - Is there a way I could get the session of Cassandra started by `TestCassandra`?
question2 - is there a better way for me to organise the classes?

Answer (score 0):

> question1 - Is there a way I could get the session of Cassandra
>   started by TestCassandra?

There is no way to get the `Session` of `Cassandra` started by `TestCassandra`.

You can use either `com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.ClusterFactory`
or `com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.CqlSessionFactory` to create `Cluster` or `CqlSession` classes.

Comment: since 2.0.2 it is possible to do that :)

Comment: Thanks. Could you also please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56354662/how-to-get-descriptive-error-messages-from-embedded-cassandra