# how to get descriptive error messages from embedded cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am using `embedded cassandra` to run unit tests. I notice that if any `cql` statements fail, then I don't see any descriptive reason for failure. For eg. I am running the following two statements which fails because I am trying to add a table without switching to a keyspace

```
val statement1 =
        """
          |CREATE KEYSPACE test
          |  WITH REPLICATION = {
          |   'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',
          |   'replication_factor' : 1
          |  };
        """.stripMargin

      val statement3 =
        """
            |CREATE TABLE users (
            |    bucket int,
            |    email text,
            |    firstname text,
            |    lastname text,
            |    authprovider text,
            |    password text,
            |    confirmed boolean,
            |    id UUID,
            |    hasher text,
            |    salt text,
            |    PRIMARY KEY ((bucket, email), authprovider,firstname, lastname) )
        """.stripMargin

val cqlStatements:CqlStatements = new CqlStatements(statement1,statement3)

")
      val testCassandra = repoTestEnv.testCassandra


      try {
        testCassandra.start()
        testCassandra.executeScripts(cqlStatements)
      } finally testCassandra.stop()
```

But I don't see correct error. I see the following which doesn't tell exactly what is the problem

```
[info] c.g.n.e.c.l.WindowsCassandraNode - Apache Cassandra Node '7276' is started
[info] c.g.n.e.c.l.LocalCassandraDatabase - Apache Cassandra '3.11.1' is started (20811 ms)
[warn] c.d.d.c.Connection - /127.0.0.1:9042 did not send an authentication challenge; This is suspicious because the driver expects authentication (configured auth provider = com.datastax.driver.core.PlainTextAuthProvider)
[warn] c.d.d.c.Connection - /127.0.0.1:9042 did not send an authentication challenge; This is suspicious because the driver expects authentication (configured auth provider = com.datastax.driver.core.PlainTextAuthProvider)
[debug] c.g.n.e.c.t.u.CqlUtils - Executing Script: CqlStatements [
CREATE KEYSPACE test
  WITH REPLICATION = {
   'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',
   'replication_factor' : 1
  };
        ,
CREATE TABLE users (
    bucket int,
    email text,
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    authprovider text,
    password text,
    confirmed boolean,
    id UUID,
    hasher text,
    salt text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((bucket, email), authprovider,firstname, lastname) )
        ]
[debug] c.g.n.e.c.t.u.CqlUtils - Executing Statement: 
CREATE KEYSPACE test
  WITH REPLICATION = {
   'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',
   'replication_factor' : 1
  };

[info] c.g.n.e.c.Cassandra - INFO  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2019-05-29 07:50:00,788 MigrationManager.java:310 - Create new Keyspace: KeyspaceMetadata{name=test, params=KeyspaceParams{durable_writes=true, replication=ReplicationParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy, replication_factor=1}}, tables=[], views=[], functions=[], types=[]}
[debug] c.g.n.e.c.t.u.CqlUtils - Executing Statement: 
CREATE TABLE users (
    bucket int,
    email text,
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    authprovider text,
    password text,
    confirmed boolean,
    id UUID,
    hasher text,
    salt text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((bucket, email), authprovider,firstname, lastname) )

[debug] c.g.n.e.c.t.TestCassandra - Stop TestCassandra 3.11.1
[info] c.g.n.e.c.l.LocalCassandraDatabase - Stop Apache Cassandra '3.11.1'
[debug] c.g.n.e.c.l.RunProcess - Execute 'powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted C:\Users\manu\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded-cassandra\3.11.1\0d155e04-97d5-4927-87ac-d46824a77c32\bin\stop-server.ps1 -p C:\Users\manu\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded-cassandra\3.11.1\0d155e04-97d5-4927-87ac-d46824a77c32\1da63488-2624-4141-a49e-174203b7edc4' within a directory 'C:\Users\manu\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded-cassandra\3.11.1\0d155e04-97d5-4927-87ac-d46824a77c32'
[info] c.g.n.e.c.Cassandra - INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-05-29 07:50:03,926 HintsService.java:220 - Paused hints dispatch
[info] c.g.n.e.c.Cassandra - INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-05-29 07:50:03,933 Server.java:176 - Stop listening for CQL clients
[info] c.g.n.e.c.Cassandra - INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-05-29 07:50:03,934 Gossiper.java:1532 - Announcing shutdown
[info] c.g.n.e.c.Cassandra - INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-05-29 07:50:03,938 StorageService.java:2268 - Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to shutdown
[info] c.g.n.e.c.Cassandra - INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-05-29 07:50:05,941 MessagingService.java:984 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
[info] c.g.n.e.c.Cassandra - INFO  [ACCEPT-localhost/127.0.0.1] 2019-05-29 07:50:05,948 MessagingService.java:1338 - MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
[info] c.g.n.e.c.Cassandra - INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-05-29 07:50:06,076 HintsService.java:220 - Paused hints dispatch
[info] c.g.n.e.c.l.WindowsCassandraNode - Successfully sent ctrl+c to process with id: 7276.
[info] c.g.n.e.c.l.WindowsCassandraNode - Apache Cassandra Node '7276' is stopped
[info] c.g.n.e.c.l.LocalCassandraDatabase - Apache Cassandra '3.11.1' is stopped (3490 ms)
[info] c.g.n.e.c.l.LocalCassandraDatabase - The working directory 'C:\Users\manu\AppData\Local\Temp\embedded-cassandra\3.11.1\0d155e04-97d5-4927-87ac-d46824a77c32' was deleted.
[debug] c.g.n.e.c.t.TestCassandra - TestCassandra 3.11.1 is stopped

Unable to start TestCassandra 3.11.1
com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.CassandraException: Unable to start TestCassandra 3.11.1
    at com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.TestCassandra.start(TestCassandra.java:128)
    at UnitSpecs.RepositorySpecs.UsersRepositorySpecs.$anonfun$new$3(UsersRepositorySpecs.scala:146)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
```

Ideally I should get the error similar to what I would get if I was using `cqlsh`

Is there a way to get more descriptive errors?

Comment: Can you show `logback.xml` ? Seems like your `logback` configuration does not include `caused` exception.

Comment: logback.xml - `<logger name="com.github.nosan" level="ALL">`

Comment: Could you try this `logback.xml` please:

```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} %m%n%xEx{5}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.github.nosan" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>```
And run once again.

Comment: I added the following two but no luck!  `<logger name="com.github.nosan" level="DEBUG" additivity="false"> <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/> </logger>
  <logger name="com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.TestCassandra" level="ALL" />`

Comment: Have you tried the `appender` configuration which I sent before?

Comment: yes, its there `<appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce your issue, but no luck.

```java
import com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.cql.CqlScript;
import com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.TestCassandra;

class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestCassandra testCassandra = new TestCassandra(CqlScript.statements(createKeyspace(),
                createUserTable()));
        testCassandra.start();
        try {
            System.out.println(testCassandra.getSettings());
        }
        finally {
            testCassandra.stop();
        }
    }

    private static String createUserTable() {
        return "CREATE TABLE users ( bucket int, "
                + "email text, "
                + "firstname text, "
                + "lastname text, "
                + "authprovider text, "
                + "password text, "
                + "confirmed boolean, "
                + "id UUID, hasher text, "
                + "salt text, "
                + "PRIMARY KEY ((bucket, email), authprovider,firstname, lastname) )";
    }

    private static String createKeyspace() {
        return "CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1}";
    }

}
```

Output:

```java
Exception in thread "main" com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.CassandraException: Unable to start TestCassandra 3.11.4
    at com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.TestCassandra.start(TestCassandra.java:156)
    at com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.Scratch.main(Scratch.java:27)
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: No keyspace has been specified. USE a keyspace, or explicitly specify keyspace.tablename
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:48)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:113)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:53)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:30)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:207)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession.execute(CqlSession.java:47)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession.execute(CqlSession.java:56)
    at com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.util.CqlUtils.execute(CqlUtils.java:68)
    at com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.util.CqlUtils.execute(CqlUtils.java:47)
    at com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.util.CqlSessionUtils.execute(CqlSessionUtils.java:43)
    at com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.CqlSessionConnection.execute(CqlSessionConnection.java:60)
    at com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.DefaultConnection.execute(DefaultConnection.java:53)
    at com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.TestCassandra.executeScripts(TestCassandra.java:256)
    at com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.TestCassandra.doStart(TestCassandra.java:285)
    at com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.TestCassandra.start(TestCassandra.java:147)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep trying to find out what might be the issue. On separate note, do I need both  `<artifactId>embedded-cassandra</artifactId>` and `artifactId>embedded-cassandra-test</artifactId>`? I just noticed that I have added only `artifactId>embedded-cassandra-test</artifactId>` dependency. Does `embedded-cassandra-test` automatically includes `embedded-cassandra` dependency

Comment: you don't need to add `embedded-cassandra` if you have already added `embedded-cassandra-test`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find my `Caused` isn't printed but I have found this workaround

```
  try {
    testCassandra.start()
    println(s"cassandra state is ${testCassandra.getState}")
    testCassandra.executeScripts(cqlStatements)
    //println(s"result of execution is ${result}")
    //val settings = testCassandra.getSettings
    //println(s"settings are ${settings}")
  } catch {
    case e:Exception => {
      println(s"exception ${e} caused by ${e.getCause}")
      //println(s"caused by ${e.getCause()}")
     fail( new Throwable(e.getCause))
    }
  }finally {
    testCassandra.stop()

  }
```

the above prints

```
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException was thrown.
ScalaTestFailureLocation: UnitSpecs.RepositorySpecs.UsersRepositorySpecs at (UsersRepositorySpecs.scala:157)
...
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: No keyspace has been specified. USE a keyspace, or explicitly specify keyspace.tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. I wasn't using `TestCassandra` correctly it seems. I didn't realize that if I create `TestCassandra` and also specify the `cql` statements at time of instantiation, the `start` method runs the queries as well. In my code, I was creating `TestCassandra` as follows

`new TestCassandra(factory,cqlStatements)})`

and was calling both `start` and `executeScripts`

```
testCassandra.start()
testCassandra.executeScripts(cqlStatements)
```

I commented that `executeScripts` line and I now see both `Exception` and `Caused`

I think it would be better if the APIs clearly mention that start has side effect of executing statements as well.